# How to properly use shared pointer member of a struct?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a struct containing a shared_ptr to a vector. In my code I am getting 3 errors related to this:

- > At this line, 
  >       `newtickerDiary t;
  >       t.dataPtr->reserve(MAX_OHLC_ENTRIES);
  >       tDiaries[token] = t;` 
  >  I get this error: 
  >  **function "newtickerDiary::operator=(const newtickerDiary &)" (declared
  >   implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function**
- > At this line,
  > `QuotationWTime &prevQ = tDiaries[token].dataPtr[size -> 1];`
  >  I get the following error: 
  >   **no operator "[]" matches these operands**
- > At this line,
  >  `for (auto x : tDiaries)
  >          {
  >              x.second.updatesOn = false;
  >          }`
  >  I get the following error: 
  >  **function "std::pair<_Ty1, _Ty2>::pair(const std::pair<_Ty1, _Ty2> &) [with _Ty1=const std::string, _Ty2=newtickerDiary]" (declared at line 133 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
  >   Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include\utility")
  >   cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function**

Following are relevant data containers/types:

```
typedef int16_t int16;
typedef int32_t int32;

struct QuotationWTime {
    union AmiDate DateTime; // 8 byte
    float   Price;
    float   Open;
    float   High;
    float   Low;
    float   Volume;
    float   OpenInterest;
    float   AuxData1;
    float   AuxData2;
};

struct newtickerDiary {
    string name = ""; //AmiBroker scrip name
    string ohlcPeriodicity = "minute"; //interval of fetched OHLC data
    bool ohlcStatus = false; //updated initially. Will be set to 0 upon plugin initialization
    bool rtStatus = false;//updated initially. Will be set to 0 upon plugin initialization
    bool updatesOn = true;
    int32 ohlcDayBarIndex = 0; //last updated bar
    shared_ptr<vector<QuotationWTime>> dataPtr = std::make_shared<std::vector<QuotationWTime>>();
    mutex dataMutex;
};

unordered_map<string, newtickerDiary> tDiaries;
```

I need help to figure out how to resolve these errors.

Comment: I am unable to copy-and-paste your code to repro the problem.  If you could provide a [mcve], that would help us to diagnose what is going awry.  As it is, I'd have to code up a lot of additional code to see the problem, and if the problem isn't in the code provided, I may not code up the same bug as in your code.  Help us help you.

Comment: Seriously, you should provide minimal code that reproduce the error. (1) The code for the first error is not is your code sample. (2) AmiDate is not defined and probably useless for that question. (3) The expression `size -> 1` is strange.

Comment: `tDiaries[token].dataPtr` would return a shared pointer. You probably need to dereference it to get the vector. That is, you should use something like `auto &v = *tDiaries[token].dataPtr;` If an expression is too complex for you, then break it down.

Comment: You should almost always use a reference in range loop if your items are not trivial type: `for (auto & x : tDiaries)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::mutex` is not copyable, nor movable. And because `newtickerDiary` has a member of type `std::mutex`, it's not copyable or movable either (at least, not implicitly; you can provide explicit copy/move constructors and assignment operators).

This is why `tDiaries[token] = t;` fails to compile - it attempts to copy an instance of `newtickerDiary`. This has nothing to do with `std::shared_ptr`.

---

Similarly, `for (auto x : tDiaries)` attempts to copy elements of `tDiaries`, and fails as they are not copyable. You likely don't want copies here anyway (or else assigning to `x.second.updatesOn` would be rather pointless). Make it

```
for (auto& x : tDiaries)
```

Note the ampersand.

---

`tDiaries[token].dataPtr[size - 1]` fails because `tDiaries[token].dataPtr` is not an array or a container - it's a pointer to one. Make it

```
(*tDiaries[token].dataPtr)[size - 1]
```